# How To Sync Timers

Tags: c#

I have two timers in a windows form app.

I want first timer1 to enable by button1 click.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

What i want to know is how to do following:

The first timer1 must fire once(tick once) and then stop.

And the second timer2 to start after 20 seconds of timer1 tick.

Comment: Why don't you use a third timer that triggers timer 1 and 2 after 20s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval= 20000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
    //you job here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `timer1` Interval to the 20*1000 (20 seconds) before starting the `timer1`.

You need to stop the `timer1` in the `timer1_Tick` event handler and start the `timer2`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval= 20*1000; //20 seconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    timer2.Start(); //or timer2.Enabled=true;
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever you want in timer2 Tick event handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would add a third timer that would launch the timer 1 and the timer 2 after 20s.